# Jquery collision: draggable and target collision event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using jQuery collision with draggable. I have code working to change the color of the target (the larger box) on drop. However, I would like it to change color as soon as the `dragMe` touches it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rebeccaoutofourmindsstudios/mgL968x4/2/

```js
$(".dragMe").draggable({
  obstacle: ".obstacle",
  preventCollision: true,
  containment: "#moveInHere"
});

$(".obstacle").draggable({
  obstacle: ".dragMe",
  preventCollision: true,
  containment: "#moveInHere"
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dragMe").draggable({
    containment: ".moveInHere",
    obstacle: ".obstacle"
  });
  $("#obstacle").draggable({
    containment: ".moveInHere"
  });
  $("#Target1").droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    preventCollision: true,
    drop: dropItem
  });
});

function dropItem(ev, ui) {
  $("#Target1").css({
    background: "blue"
  });

}
```

```css
#moveInHere {
  with: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}

.dragMe {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}

.obstacle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}

.target {
  postition: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eruciform.com/static//jquidragcollide/jquery-collision.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eruciform.com/static//jquidragcollide/jquery-ui-draggable-collision.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="moveInHere" id="moveInHere">
    <div class="dragMe" id="dragMe">Drag me...</div>
    <div class="obstacle" id="obstacle">...but not in here.</div>
    <div class="target" id="Target1">I want to change color</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`over`](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over) event callback like this:

```
over: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css('background', 'dodgerblue');
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dragMe").draggable({
    obstacle: ".obstacle",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere"
  });

  $(".obstacle").draggable({
    obstacle: ".dragMe",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere"
  });

  $("#Target1").droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    preventCollision: true,
    over: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).css('background', 'dodgerblue');
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).css('background', '#eee');
    },
    drop: dropItem
  });
});

function dropItem(ev, ui) {
  $(this).css({
    background: "blue"
  });
}
```

```css
#moveInHere {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}

.dragMe {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}

.obstacle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eruciform.com/static//jquidragcollide/jquery-collision.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eruciform.com/static//jquidragcollide/jquery-ui-draggable-collision.js"></script>

<div class="moveInHere" id="moveInHere">
  <div class="dragMe" id="dragMe">Drag me...</div>
  <div class="obstacle" id="obstacle">...but not in here.</div>
  <div class="target" id="Target1">I want to change color</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `hoverClass:` in the droppable definition (like mentioned in the [jquery.ui documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-hoverClass)) and apply the background-color to that class.

**Working example:**

```js
$(".dragMe").draggable({
    obstacle: ".obstacle",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere"
});

$(".obstacle").draggable({
    obstacle: ".dragMe",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere"
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dragMe").draggable({ containment: ".moveInHere", obstacle: ".obstacle" });
  $("#obstacle").draggable({ containment: ".moveInHere" });
  $("#Target1").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    tolerance: "touch",
    preventCollision: true,
    drop: dropItem
  });
  });

function dropItem(ev, ui) {
    $("#Target1").css({ background: "blue" });
  
}
```

```css
#moveInHere {
    with: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;
}
.dragMe{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;
}
.obstacle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;
}
.target{
    postition: absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:200px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;
}
.target.drop-hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eruciform.com/static//jquidragcollide/jquery-collision.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eruciform.com/static//jquidragcollide/jquery-ui-draggable-collision.js"></script>

<div class="moveInHere" id="moveInHere">
    <div class="dragMe" id="dragMe">Drag me...</div>
    <div class="obstacle" id="obstacle">...but not in here.</div>
    <div class="target" id="Target1">I want to change color</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).